# Getting a count of number of rows matching MAX() value in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called 'games' that has a column in it called 'week'. I am trying to find a single query that will give me the maximum value for 'week' along with a count of how many rows in that table have the maximum value for 'week'. I could split it up into two queries:

```
SELECT MAX(week) FROM games
// store value in a variable $maxWeek
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM games WHERE week = $maxWeek
// store that result in a variable
```

Is there a way to do this all in one query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT week, count(*) FROM games GROUP BY week ORDER BY week DESC LIMIT 1;
```

or

```
SELECT week, count(*) FROM games WHERE week = (SELECT max(week) FROM games) GROUP BY week;
```

(may be faster)

Comment: I went with the second one, and I must admit I thought about using GROUP BY and ORDER but didn't think it would work. :P

Comment: Why wouldn't it? ;-) Have you checked with `explain` if the second one is better? Just wondering…